# Generic organic stain/dirt shape

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am a searching for a algorithm which in essence returns an array of points which define the shape of a stain formed by liquid.

I need no directional influence, it could be a stain produced by a drop falling vertically down.

I started to spread points from a center in pairs of two, one closer to the center one near, which gives me a star ofcourse. But then i ideas left me. How can i avaoid intersections and the like but mostly: For a one-shape solution without any fancy sidedrops there should be a algorithm available i am not aware of? So any ideas/solutions?

Examples of stain i mean (i only need the central/main shape ofcourse):
[related stains on Google-Images](https://www.google.de/search?q=fleck&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tIT3VMisEs7sO6ObgZAM&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1539&bih=854)

Comment: You need a graphic designer. This is off-topic as it stands - you should try to come up with something yourself, **and show us** first.

Comment: You haven't exactly defined how your desired set of points will describe the stain -  Is the stain a bitmap image? Do you want the set of points that describes the line segments of the stain's outline? How accurately?

One approach would be to trace the border of the stain into a set of points that describe the line segments that define the shape. To that end you would be looking at "border tracing algorithms" or "contour tracing algorithms". Not sure about the performance of doing something like that in javascript though!

Comment: @ArtOfCode i am talking about a array of points, and as i said generic, so why do you think a graphic designer could be of help?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do a job that would be better handled by a graphic designer.

Comment: @Matt Coubrough as i said, a array of points describing an outline at the best though i could apply a hull-algorithm by myself. Best case would be around i don`t know 40 points in order with known direction (left hand right hand). But well as i said that is the best case. I am missing an idea to generate the basic shape though there should be algorithms to describe the basics.

Comment: @ArtOfCode There are tons of vector graphics for stain out there, so why should be my intention be to do a designers job?

Comment: Google Radial sweep contour tracing to get you started

Comment: That's what it sounds like. What are your intentions?

Comment: @ArtOfCode actually this is not the place to discuss this here but to give you something to think. I am building a website for kids where they can play with paint-tools. Everything works with vectors, the whole gui is scaleable and the like. And i have a "stain" tool which i want to make generic stains without the need of using svgs or pngs as a base. Perhaps i will use graphics in the end but i pay 6 graphic designers every month so no need on that side. So in the end this is a experimental idea i am following. Do you need more information, and happy downvoting -.-?

Comment: The downvote is not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refine you star approach by making the lines Bézier curves. If you look at the examples of your search, you will basically see two patterns of splashes: Small thin spikes and larger drop-like shapes.

We can ditsribute splashes randomly on a circle and also determine a splash length. Then we decide which of the shapes to draw based on that length. The control points we need are:

[image: Bézier control points]

The code below tries to model that. The funtion `splash` returns a list of coordinates of a splash centered at the origin. The list has `3*n + 1` points for a closed curve of `n` Bézier segments. (`n` is determined randomly.)

The code is far from perfect and also has too much auxiliary stuff, which can be improved, but might give you an idea:

```
var rnd = {
    uniform: function(n) {
            return Math.floor(n * Math.random());
        },

    range: function(from, to) {
            return from + this.uniform(to - from);
        },

    float: function(from, to) {
            return from + (to - from) * Math.random();
        }
}

var coord = {
    radiants: function(x) {
            return Math.PI * x / 180.0;
        },

    degrees: function(x) {
            return 180.0 * x / Math.PI;
        },

    cartesian: function(P) {
            return {
                x: P.r * Math.cos(P.phi),
                y: P.r * Math.sin(P.phi)
            }
        },

    mid: function(P, Q, a) {
            if (!a) a = 0.5;

            return {
                x: (1 - a) * P.x + a * Q.x,
                y: (1 - a) * P.y + a * Q.y
            };
        },

    normal: function(P, len) {
            if (!len) len = 1;
            var l = Math.sqrt(P.x*P.x + P.y*P.y);

            return {
                x: len * P.y / l, 
                y: -len * P.x / l
            };
        },

    add: function(P, Q) {
            return {
                x: P.x + Q.x,
                y: P.y + Q.y
            };
        },

    mul: function(P, a) {
            return {
                x: a * P.x,
                y: a * P.y
            };
        },

    dist: function(P, Q) {
            var dx = P.x - Q.x;
            var dy = P.y - Q.y;

            var l = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        },

    normalize: function(P, len) {
            if (!len) len = 1;
            var l = Math.sqrt(P.x*P.x + P.y*P.y);

            return {
                x: len * P.x / l, 
                y: len * P.y / l
            };
        }
}

function get(param, value, dflt) {
    if (value in param) return param[value];
    return dflt;
}

function splash(param) {
    var r = get(param, "r", 10);
    var minangle = get(param, "minangle", 5);
    var maxangle = get(param, "maxangle", 30);
    var ratio = get(param, "ratio", 2.4);
    var n = get(param, "n", 2);

    var radial = [];
    var phi = 0;

    while (phi < 2 * Math.PI) {
        radial.push({
            phi: phi, 
            r: r * (1 + (ratio - 1) * Math.pow(Math.random(), n))
        });
        phi += coord.radiants(rnd.float(minangle, maxangle, 30));
    }

    var phi0 = coord.radiants(rnd.float(0, 10));
    for (var i = 0; i < radial.length; i++) {
        var rr = radial[i];

        rr.phi =  2 * rr.phi * Math.PI / phi + phi0;
    }

    var res = [];

    var prev = radial[radial.length - 1];
    var curr = radial[0];
    var C = {x: 0, y: 0};

    for (var i = 0; i < radial.length; i++) {
        var next = radial[(i + 1) % radial.length];

        var ML = coord.cartesian(prev);
        var MR = coord.cartesian(next);
        var M = coord.cartesian(curr);

        var L = coord.mid(C, coord.mid(ML, M));
        var R = coord.mid(C, coord.mid(MR, M));
        if (i == 0) res.push(L);

        var dphi = (next.phi - prev.phi);
        if (dphi < 0) dphi += 2 * Math.PI;
        var dr = 0.5 * r * dphi;

        var NL = coord.normal(L, -dr * rnd.float(0.3, 0.45));
        res.push(coord.add(L, NL));

        console.log((curr.r - r) / (ratio - 1));
        if (Math.random() > (curr.r - r) / r / (ratio - 1)) {
            // little splash
            var MM = coord.mid(C, M, rnd.float(0.75, 0.95));

            res.push(MM);
            res.push(M);
            res.push(MM);                
        } else {
            // drop-shaped splash
            var s = dr * rnd.float(0.2, 0.5);
            var t = dr * rnd.float(0.02, 0.2);

            var MM = coord.mid(coord.mid(L, M), coord.mid(R, M));
            var Mpos = coord.normalize(M, s);
            var Mneg = coord.normalize(M, -s);

            var MT = coord.add(M, Mpos);

            var NML = coord.normal(M, s);
            var NLL = coord.normal(M, t);
            var MML = coord.add(MM, NLL);
            var ML = coord.add(M, NML);

            var NMR = coord.normal(M, -s);
            var NRR = coord.normal(M, -t);
            var MMR = coord.add(MM, NRR);
            var MR = coord.add(M, NMR);

            res.push(coord.mid(C, MML, 0.8));
            res.push(MML);
            res.push(coord.mid(C, MML, 1.25));

            res.push(coord.add(ML, coord.mul(Mneg, 0.55)));
            res.push(ML);
            res.push(coord.add(ML, coord.mul(Mpos, 0.55)));

            res.push(coord.add(MT, coord.mul(NML, 0.55)));
            res.push(MT);
            res.push(coord.add(MT, coord.mul(NMR, 0.55)));

            res.push(coord.add(MR, coord.mul(Mpos, 0.55)));
            res.push(MR);
            res.push(coord.add(MR, coord.mul(Mneg, 0.55)));

            res.push(coord.mid(C, MMR, 1.25));
            res.push(MMR);
            res.push(coord.mid(C, MMR, 0.8));
        }

        var NR = coord.normal(R, dr * rnd.float(0.3, 0.45));
        res.push(coord.add(R, NR));
        res.push(R);

        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }

    return res;
}
```

And an example of how to use that code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var cv = document.getElementById("plot");
    var cx = cv.getContext("2d");

    var p = splash({
        r: 100,
        ratio: 1.6,
        n: 1
    });

    cx.fillStyle = "tomato";
    cx.translate(300, 300);

    cx.beginPath();
    cx.moveTo(p[0].x, p[0].y);
    for (var i = 1; i < p.length; i++) {
        var p1 = p[i++];
        var p2 = p[i++];
        var p3 = p[i];

        cx.bezierCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y);
    }

    cx.closePath();
    cx.fill();
}
```

Comment: That gives me far more than only an idea. This is great. I was stuck today after calculating the inner and outer random points around the center. Your illustration also helps my brain alot ;)